# Upgrade main board or straight-across replace?

Tags: printer-building, electronics, flsun-3d-cube

Flsun 3D Cube; main board, MKS GEN L V1.0

I think I need to replace the main board and I don't know enough about 3D printer components yet to judge whether a 1:1 replacement would be better than selecting a different board, or keep the same board but with upgraded stepper drivers?

I've been able to do everything I've wanted with the printer as it was out of the box, so I have no complaints about the main board (aside from no longer heating the bed). I don't need the biggest-baddest board out there. I just don't know how to judge the pros and cons of my choices here.

Comment: Are you asking about replacement of the board or seek troubleshooting advice to conclude that you need to replace the board? You wrote a lot, but I guess the most interesting part is that the heated bed is not working anymore.

Comment: The heated bed is being dealt with in another post. I'm thinking about upgrading or replacing or something regardless. I just don't know how to make my choices.